# Scraping javascript data from table or grid

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to scrape data from a grid. I need all the data within the grid - (data containing Ticker , Score, Company, Exchange, and so on.

I am using Selenium to open the page and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I've tried some tutorials but the code seems different. I've tried to scrape using the table "maintable-multi-1067-body" and I've also tried the grid "gridview-1070" but nothing is working. If anyone could show me how to do this, I'd appreciate it.

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd
    
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
ser = Service("./chromedriver.exe")
browser = driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://stockrover.com")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/ul/li[2]"))).click()
user = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
user.clear()
user.send_keys("test11964")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("test21964")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Sign In").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tbody#maintable-multi-1067-body tr')))

for tab in table:
  print(tab.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to the working code but there are still several issues here:

1. Your `table` locator is wrong.
   Instead of

```py
'tbody#maintable-multi-1067-body tr'
```

Try using
Instead of

```py
'#maintable-multi-1067-body tr'
```

It will give you 502 results.
2) No need to define 3 times the `wait` object

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
```

Comment: Wow, you're the best!  Now, I just need to figure out how to get it a readable format in a csv file and get it to do all the pages.  Thanks again

Comment: You are sincerely welcome! As about how to put that in a csv file and paging please open a new questions. SO rules saying each question should be about a single, concrete problem.